# Composite Pattern and can it be used for DailyPay (leaf) and PayPeriod (Composite)?

Tags: design-patterns

As I am fairly new to design patterns and trying to implement some of them in my personal projects I am confused if the composite pattern is applicable for my use. I am attempting to calculate pay for a single day and store it in a pay period. DailyPay is my 'leaf' and PayPeriod my 'composite'.

Does it even make sense to do this? In this scenario, I am calculating pay for tractor-trailer drivers who are paid per stop, mileage, and trailers drop. Then attempting to keep track of 7 days of pay and calculate the weekly pay and then monthly.

Answer (score 0):

Should I use the Composite Pattern?

The Composite Pattern is an abstraction that *assumes the interface of another abstraction* only to *forward* requests to *multiple* instances of said interface. It's not just used for trees, though GoF book uses it in that context:

- It can be used anywhere you'd like to substitute a group for a singular and vice versa.

Consider this:

[image: Composite Pattern]

The client requires an `IPayPeriod`. `WeeklyPayPeriod` aggregates net pay from `DailyPayPeriod`s.